# Tab press doesn't go forward on form fields in chrome/IE11

Tags: javascript, html

I have form which has password field when i press tab key it moves through textboxes but when it reaches to password field it doesn't moves forward or backward. The Firefox doesn't shows this problem but chrome and IE11 shows this problem.

```
<tr>
      <td  style="text-align:left"><label for="name"> Name<font color="red">*</font> </label></td>
      <td ><input type="text" id="doctorName" name="doc_name" placeholder="Name" onblur="allLetter(document.registration.doc_name)"  required />
      </td><td><img src="images2/image.png" class="masterTooltip" title="eg. Mr|Ms|Dr|Smt  Last First Middle name"></td><td style="text-align:left"><i name="nameb"style='color:red' id='docnm' ></i></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"> <label for="email" > Email </label></td>
      <td  ><input type="text" id="doctorEmail" name="doc_email" onblur="myfun()" placeholder="Email"  required /></td><td><img src="images2/image.png" class="masterTooltip" title="Enter valid email for eg. abcd@example.com"></td>
      <td style="text-align:left"> <i style='color:red' id='email' ></i></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"> <label for="uname" >User Name<font color="red">*</font></label></td>
      <td ><input type="text" id="userName" name="username" onblur="allLetter_username(document.registration.username)" placeholder="User Name"  required />
      </td><td><img src="images2/image.png" class="masterTooltip" title="UserName contains a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _"></td><td style="text-align:left"><i name="nameb"style='color:red' id='usernm' ></i></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left"> <label for="password" >Password<font color="red">*</font> </label></td>
      <td ><input type="password" id="doctorPassword" name="doc_password" onblur="passid_validation(7,20)" placeholder="Password"   /><td></td>
      </td><td style="text-align:left"> <i style='color:red' id='pass' ></i></td>
      </tr>


// This function will validate Password.
function passid_validation(mx,my)
{
    var passid = document.registration.doc_password;
    var passid_len = passid.value.length;
    if (passid_len == 0 ||passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx)
    {
        document.getElementById('pass').innerHTML="Password length must     be 7 to 20";
        passid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('pass').innerHTML='';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly set the tabindex on your inputs. Check [this](http://webcheatsheet.com/HTML/controll_tab_order.php) out

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

```
onblur="passid_validation(7,20)"
```

event. It has to somehow prevent from further tabbing.

Comment: passid.focus(); puts focus back on the password control